# Semantic-UI: How to change dimmer background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I want to change color of dimmer of my modal, but I can't! what should I do?

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Profile Picture
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>sth</p>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black button">
      Nope
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
      Yep, that's me
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## In JS:

I tried for example following code, yet, no change!

```
$('.ui.modal').each(function() {
    $(this).modal({allowMultiple: true}).modal('show').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `background-color` property on element `.dimmer` with an `rgba` type css color value to introduce transparency.

```
.dimmer { background-color: rgba(250,250,50,0.8) }
```

To apply this CSS using jQuery, use the `jQuery#css` method like so:

```
$(".dimmer").css("background-color","rgba(250,250,50,0.8)");
```

Comment: Hi, No change, syntax error, and event if I use `.dimmer({background-color: white})` no change again!

Comment: I applied it in the separated CSS file and even I used `!important` after it!